# Drupal 7 Custom theme and custom module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I know drupal a bit.

I am creating a custom theme and defined a region in my themename.info as

```
regions[search] = Search Bar
```

And added the below code to my page.tpl.php

```
<div id="search" class="search_box">
  <?php if ($page['search']): ?>    
    <?php print render($page['search']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>  
</div>
```

And I enabled search form via Block administration, so everything is fine now.

But, I want to create my custom search module. Please provide me some sample code, so that I can understand.

In explanation, I want to create a hook menu and function which can print what I want and also how can I enable the function to be printed on the region.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal each piece of content that can be placed into a region is called a "block". So instead you want to create a Custom Block. Here's a guide, http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2012/07/18/building-custom-blocks-drupal-7.

https://drupal.org/node/1074360, Here is the Drupal module creation tutorial, the guide "generating block content" will be helpful for you.